# startSSL class 2 certificate

Tags: ssl, certificate

StartSSL.com seems to be selling cheap SSL certs, but I wonder if anyone actually have experience using their certs.

StartSSL™ Verified   StartSSL™ Verified (Class 2) digital certificates are ideal for authentication, B2B and B2C transactions, protection of electronic mail and signing of **object code and macros**. More than that, StartSSL™ Verified provides a level of flexibility and support options not found anywhere else. StartSSL™ Verified supports:
Web server certificates (SSL/TLS)
Wild cards (*.domain.com)
Multiple domains (DNS Alt Names)
128/256-bit encryption
Object Code Signing
Client and mail certificates (S/MIME)
US $ 10,000 insurance guaranteed
Certificates 2 Years valid (730 days)

**Is it safe to share personal passport information and company information with them for personal/organization validated certs?**
(their website looks crapy and help email bouncing)

I am interested in signing code, and if that works for web server as well, that would be great.

Any other alternatives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit in February 2018**
As noted by others in the comments, StartSSL certificates are no longer trusted by browsers, and they are no longer issued. I recommend taking a look at [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) instead.

**Original answer**
I just signed up with them. After submitting my passport (with some info blacked out, just in case) I got a call almost instantly from a representative wanting to verify some information.

Haven't found any info about them being shady, and given that they have been accepted as a root CA by Microsoft, I believe they are legit.

Comment: I have bought a class 2 certificate from startssl. Their technical support is very efficent. I strongly recommend them.

Comment: Should be noted that they charge 59.99 for validating your identity and then additional 59.99 for validating your company, then an additional 59.99 for a Class 2 certificate, so in total: ~177$

Comment: They don't accept blacked out/hidden signatures or information any longer and they also require TWO ID documents. This would making it easy for them to do identity theft it they wanted to. Or in a worst case scenario they could take over a company with that information - i'd rather go with comodo for now.

Comment: I'm currently nervously going through this process with them, having sent scanned copies of my passport and driving license they also have requested a phone bill (with no details blacked out).

Comment: StartSSL is dead, distrusted by Chrome, FF, Apple; and they do not issue certificates anymore.